# How do I re-issue a corrected group donation

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

I issued a combined Receipt for a dozen donation from a donor. I subsequently determined one of the donations should have been cancelled/deleted. I deleted the incorrect donation and cancelled the Official Receipt. There appears to be no way to issue a corrected Receipt, short of deleting and reentering each of the valid donations.

Comment: I think that is correct. You can do it by fiddling in the database in the cdntax tables but I don't recommend that, or at least if you do then keep backups or a log of what you did in case it comes up later (I am not a tax lawyer - this is technical not legal advice).